# use lag int the next line after its line have been executed

Tags: oracle, procedure

This is a very complicated situation for me and I was wondering if someone can help me with it:

Here is my table:

```
Record_no   Type    Solde   SQLCalculatedPmu    DesiredValues
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2570088 Insertion   60          133               133
2636476 Insertion   67          119,104           119,104
2636477 Insertion   68          117,352           117,352
2958292 Insertion   74          107,837           107,837
3148350 Radiation   73          107,837           107,83  <---
3282189 Insertion   80          98,401            98,395
3646066 Insertion   160         49,201            49,198
3783510 Insertion   176         44,728            44,725
3783511 Insertion   177         44,475            44,472
4183663 Insertion   188         41,873            41,87
4183664 Insertion   189         41,651            41,648
4183665 Radiation   188         41,651            41,64   <---
4183666 Insertion   195         40,156            40,145
4183667 Insertion   275         28,474            28,466
4183668 Insertion   291         26,908            26,901
4183669 Insertion   292         26,816            26,809
4183670 Insertion   303         25,842            25,836
4183671 Insertion   304         25,757            25,751
```

In my table every value in the `SQLCalculatedPmu` column or `desiredValue` Column is calculated based on the preceding value.

As you can see, I have calculated the `SQLcalculatedPMU` column based on the round on 3 decimals. The case is that on each line radiation, the client want to start the next calculation based on 2 decimals instead of 3(represented in the desired values column). Next values will be recalculated. For example line 6 will change as the value in line 5 is now on 2 decimals. I could handle this if there where one single radiation but in my case I have a lot of Radiations and in this case they will change all based on the calculation of the two decimals.

In summary, Here are the steps:

```
1 - round the value of the preceding row of a raditaiton and put it in the radiation row. 
2 - calculate all next insertion rows. 
3 - when we reach another radiation we redo steps 1 and 2 and so on
```

I m using an oracle DB and I m the owner so I can make procedures, insert, update, select.
But I m not familiar with procedures or loops.

For information, this is the formula for SQLCalculatedPmu uses two additional culmns price and number and this is calculated every line cumulativelly for each investor:

```
  (price * number)+(cumulative (price*number) of the preceeding lines)
```

I tried something like this :

```
update PMUTemp

    set SQLCalculatedPmu = 
    case when Type = 'Insertion' then
        (number*price)+lag(SQLCalculatedPmu ,1) over (partition by investor
        order by  Record_no)/
        (number+lag(solde,1) over (partition by investor order by Record_no)) 
        else 
        TRUNC(lag(SQLCalculatedPmu,1) over partition by invetor order by  Record_no)) 
    end;
```

but I gave me this error (I think it's because I m looking at the preceiding line that itself is modified during the SQL statement) :

```
ORA-30486 : window function are allowed only in the SELECT list of a query.
```

I was wondering if creating a procedure that will be called as many time as the number of radiations would do the job but I m really not good in procedures

Any help
Regards,

---

just to make my need simpler, all I want is to have the DesiredValues column starting from the SQLCalculatedPmu    column. Steps are

```
1 - on a radiation the value become = trunc(preceding value,2) 
2 - calculate all next insertion rows this  way : (price * number)+(cumulative (price*number) of the preceeding lines). As the radiation value have changed then I need to recalculate next lines based on it
3 - when we reach another radiation we redo steps 1 and 2 and so on
```

Kindest regards

Comment: First, you trunc, you do not round (`107,837` would be rounded to `107,84`, not `107,83`). Then, I do not understand what is the problem you face here...

Comment: @Nicholas Krasnov for example I will force my first radiation to 107,83 instead of 107,837. in this case this a new number so next lines have to be calculated based on that value so next line will show 98,395 instead of 98,401 and so on.  The problem is that also this radiation will impact next values but also the next radiation will impact its next values. so I need to make a loop to fix the values based on the new value of the first radiation and another for the change in the second radiation and so on.

Comment: By the way the radiation value is only a round to two decimals of the preceeding value so if the preceding value changed then so is the radiation value and then the radiation value will impact all next values.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov do you think this is feaseble

Answer (score 0):

You should not need a procedure here -- a SQL update of the Radiation rows in the table would do this quicker and more reliably.

Something like ..

```
update my_table t1
set    (column_1, column_2) = 
       (select round(column_1,2), round(column_2,2)
        from   my_table t2
        where  t2.type      = 'Insertion' and
               t2.record_no = (select max(t3.record_no)
                               from   my_table t3
                               where  t3.type      = 'Insertion' and 
                                      t3.record_no < t1.record_no  ))
where  t1.type = 'Radiation'
```

Comment: Hello, The fact is not to change the radiation row only. Here are the steps: 1 - rownd the value of the preceding row of a raditaiton and put it in the radiation row. 2 - calculate all next insertion rows. 3 - when we reach another radiation we redo steps 1 and 2 and so on

Comment: what's the logic for calculating the insertion rows?

Comment: there are two other columns called price and number. The logic is to calculate the cumulative multiplication of these two values for all order numbers less or equal to the order number that is treated.

Comment: And into which column does that cumulative product go?

Comment: into SQLCalculatedPmu so its values are good the only thing is that when its a radiation then comes the problem of the round and the calculations that I need to make and described in steps 1 and 2

Comment: I was wondering if a loop instruction will do the job of turning the same number of time as number of radiations and make the calculation but I m really bad in that

Comment: do you think this is feaseble